# View database values in new window-C#

Tags: c#, sql, datagrid

The code here displays the values into my datagrid that is on the same page, but I want to display the database values onto a new page using the same buton. Any suggestions?

```
        string Query = "SELECT * FROM database;";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, conn);

        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        dataGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have your datagrid on a separate `.aspx` page (assuming that you are talking about ASP.NET) and then on button click redirect to that page saying

```
  protected void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  { 
     Response.Redirect("gridpage.aspx");
  }
```

In `gridpage.aspx` `page_load` event process the data and bind to gridview like

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      if(!IsPostBack)
      {
        string Query = "SELECT * FROM database;";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, conn);

        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        dataGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
       }
}
```

Comment: sorry I meant to put c# in there but forgot

Comment: is it ASP.NET or winform? You can do the same thing in both case.